# Using python: from a dictionary find all anagrams and print in descending size

Tags: python, anagram

Hi this is my first post. I have created my program so that it prints all anagrams in descending size. However it also prints all the left over words that have no anagrams which i do not want it to do. I also wondered if there was possibly a more efficient way of doing this as my way seems rather roundabout. Please help!

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

def wordIterator(dictionaryFilename):
    with open(dictionaryFilename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            word = line.strip()
            yield word

def largestAnagram(words):
    import collections
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        sortedWord = str(sorted(word))
        d[ hash(sortedWord) ].append(word)
    maxKey = max( d.keys(), key = lambda k : len(d[k]) )
    while (maxKey != 0):
        maxKey = max( d.keys(), key = lambda k : len(d[k]) )
        print(d[maxKey])
        del d[maxKey]


    return d[maxKey]

ter = wordIterator( 'dictionary.txt' )

print largestAnagram(ter)

end_time = time.time()
print("Elapsed time was %g seconds" %(end_time-start_time))
```

Comment: can you show us some line of dictionary.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want `while (maxKey > 1)`.

But your algorithm has unnecessary quadratic complexity, a more efficient
solution would be:

```
# ...
keys = [(len(v), k) for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1]
keys.sort(reverse=True)
for _, k in keys:
    print(d[k])
```